# Setting limits in the presence of undistinguishable background

Tags: probability, distributions, confidence-interval

Dear statsstackexchangers,

This seems to me like a problem that must have been tackled many times in science, but I am not certain how to proceed. How to set limits on, for example density, frequency, flux or in general, existence of objects in presence of other type of objects? The other type can be distinguished from the objects we are looking for, but only up to some point. We don't know the exact characteristics of the other type either.

Perhaps an example would clairify my question.

Imagine that we are trying to prove the existence of Yeti. We know that they live among us! So we are analysing photos of crowd gatherings hoping that we will se a Yeti among people and we will be able to say that there is, for example, 1 Yeti per 1 million people in our society. Yetis are quite easy to distinguish from people, because they are covered with dense white fur. So we look for furry people on the photos. Also, Yetis are quite tall, so if we see a 1.5 m person on the picture, it is not a Yeti. Sadly, none of analysed people has a clear fur, so we can't claim a discovery. We will try to give a limit on Yetis in the society though. We've looked through many pictures, analysed 10000 people. None of them has a clearly Yeti fur, however, in 10 cases we are uncertain. The skin/fur was not visible clearly enough. How about the height? We don't know. In most of the rejected candidates part of the person was outside of the picture, so we could not distinguish by height, but the skin/fur was visible clearly enough. In these 10 remaining candidates, parts are also outside of the picture, so we can't easily distinguish by neither the fur nor the height. How to set the limit?

If we had no candidates remaining, we could use, for example, the Rule of Three to set the 95% CL limit putting all the analysed population into the equation. But due to the 10 cases, which are most likely not Yeti, we can't.

One way that comes to my mind is just to put a hard cut on the height of people. We know that Yetis are very tall. For the sake of this example, let's say that they are always bigger than our picture. So the distribution of Yeti's height that we would see is basically flat. It can reach the full height of the picture, but can be 1 pixel if we just see the tip of the head or bottom of the heels. For people there is no established distribution of height. We know that they are much shorter, most should be within some bounds, but there are outliers. The 10 candidates that we've found have a height distrubution that is trunctuated at 0 pix on the left, and on the right falls rapidly ending at, let's say 1/4th of the picure height, with one outlier at 1/3rd. So in principle we could say, that most likely all the 10 cases are not Yetis, so we decide that everything shorter than 1/3rd of the picture is not a Yeti. This worsens our limit, because we know that there are Yetis that we would see as shorter than 1/3rd of the picture, but we don't take them into account. One of the possible problems with this approach is, that the cut is decided after we collect the samples. However, it can't be decided before, because we don't know enough about real people to know how much of the distribution of people overlaps with the distribution of Yetis. Do you think that this approach is usable? Or is it usable after some statistical modification, or is a complete rubbish? I think, despite the fact that we decide the cut based on data, it is as conservative as it gets. If we got a human outlier as tall as the picture, our limit would shrink to non-existence.

The other idea that comes to my mind is that we know that the distribution of Yetis' heights on our pictures is flat (Yeti children do not mix with us), but human is not. So perhaps we could test what is the probability that the 10 candidates that we were left with come from the flat distribution. In general, this is why we have a strong suspicion why our 10 candidates can't be Yetis - they are concentrated around small heights. Again, this would also be drawing conclusions about the background based on the experimental sample. Still, does this approach make sense? If so, what is the best way to test it?

I would apprieciate any comments or ideas. From my description of the problem you might have noticed that I am far from fluent in statistics, for sure much less than I would like to be. So it would help me a lot if you were so kind to explain your comments/ideas in a little bit more detail.

Comment: You are restating the [black swan problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_swan_theory).

Comment: Thank you. The black swan problem is new to me and I can see similarities. But I can also see differences. I don't think the candidates are unexpected and coming from the fourth-quadrant, although one could say that I think so in hindsight. We are dealing with two distributions, which we can assume have inifite tails and must cross at some point. Still, we know only the searched objects (Yeti's) distribution, but we don't know the known objects (people) distribution. So we can expect some of people in the results, but we don't know how much...

Comment: It seems that this problem can be dealt with by using, for example, "maximum gap" or "optimum interval" methods described in [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/physics/0203002.pdf), a method described [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1906.06615.pdf) and a method described [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1410.6160.pdf). How to use the last two methods two obtain a limit is another question...